# Button "Go back to the parent report" in ASP.NET ReportViewer doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting, reportviewer

I use ReportViewer control in ASP.NET. My report has "Action" on Click - Go to another report. In the another report standart button "Go back to the parent report" is active, but when I click it - nothing happens. I've tested this standart button in all browsers.
What I've to do for efficiency of this button?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I use SSDT BI 2012 and remember this question. It's worth noting that functionality in this version BI works stable in all browsers. And there is no this bug anymore.

Comment: Yeah, there are third party report viewer controls, microsoft's is somewhat buggy, specially accross browsers